# Sending parameters from a bat to bat through vbs script parameters using relative paths

Tags: parameters, vbscript, batch-file

When running `lookatbat.bat`, I receive an error that means a file (`file1WithSpaces.txt`) has not be found. I have tried using the fix in this forum, but I receive the same error even with this code.

Here's a piece of `lookatbat.bat`, it makes a call to a VBScript using relative paths.

```
cscript process.vbs /x:"Temp\file1WithSpaces.txt" /y:"Temp\file2WithSpaces.txt"
```

`process.vbs` make a call to a bat file (`InprocessVbs.bat`) which uses the first one parameter of `process.vbs`.

`process.vbs` has many instructions, here's a useful part of it:

```
dim param1: param1=Wscript.Arguments.Named("x")
dim param2: param2=Wscript.Arguments.Named("y")
msgbox param1 
shell.run "InprocessVbs.bat """ & param1 & """ ""file.txt"""
```

`msgbox param1` popups **Temp\file1WithSpaces.txt**, but I think `param1` does not retrieve properly into `InprocessVbs.bat`.

Thanks for your help!

`InprocessVbs.bat`:

```
echo %2
echo %3
echo %4
Set arg1=%1
echo %arg1%
cscript anomyze.vbs %1>spec%1
more +2 %1|findstr /n /I /r /b /C:""^R.*=001>result.out
```

Comment: What exactly makes you "think that param1 does not retrieve properly into InprocessVbs.bat"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is considered relative to the current working directory, so check what the working directory is (in both the VBScript and the batch script that is called from it), and verify that the given relative path exists below that working directory.

Check working directory in VBScript:

```
WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
```

Check working directory in batch:

```
echo %CD%
```

---

**Edit:** It's usually better to remove double quotes from a parameter and add them in the script as needed. Try this:

```
cscript anomyze.vbs "%~f1">"spec%~1"
```

You can verify if the file exists with something like this:

```
if exist "%~f1" (
  cscript anomyze.vbs "%~f1">"spec%~1"
) else (
  echo "%~f1" doesn't exist!
)
```

Also check the double quotes around the `findstr` regular expression. In your comment that part looks like this:

```
/C:""^R.*=001
```

when it should look like this:

```
/C:"^R.*=001"
```

Comment: I have checked both batch and vbs code. the current working directory is right. My 'Temp' folder really exists under this one.

Comment: Then you need to show the contents of `InprocessVbs.bat` and explain what makes you "think that param1 does not retrieve properly into InprocessVbs.bat".

Comment: I think param1 causes error because if the files are into the current working directory instead of the "Temp" folder, no problem occurs and script runs successfully( writing cscript process.vbs /x:"file1WithSpaces.txt" /y:"file2WithSpaces.txt") while cscript process.vbs /x:"Temp\file1WithSpaces.txt" /y:"Temp\file2WithSpaces.txt" results in errors

Comment: InprocessVbs.bat                                                    echo %2
echo %3
echo %4
Set arg1=%1
echo %arg1%
cscript essai.vbs %1>spec%1                                   cscript essai.vbs %2>spec%2
more +2  %1|findstr /n /I /r /b /C:""^R.*=001>result.out

Comment: your idea get answer for me.  InprocessVbs.bat is faulty. Indeed, when using relative path (with "\"), It makes cscript essai.vbs %1>spec%1 turns in error because %1 into spec%1 contains special character like "\". I have changed spec%1 to spec%~n1 to get the file name and it's so good! Thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
strCMD = "InprocessVbs.bat "&chr(34) & param1 & chr(34)&" file.txt"
shell.run strCMD
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it and receive the file is not found error over running